# HTTP Error 500.30 when deploying backend service to Azure web app service

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

I have an ASP.NET Core backend service (no UI). I also have a UI website.

The website deploys and runs correctly on app service.

The backend service deploys but does not run, also on a app service.

I get greeted with an error: HTTP Error 500.30 - ANCM In-Process Start Failure.

The files are definitely there, although they are all under wwwroot. Is that correct even if it's just a backend service?

Comment: It seems there is some issue during configure webhost. What is your program file? Try to check the log in the azure web app service. Any demo which could reproduce your issue would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Just to understand the issue correctly, when you say, "The backend service deploys but does not run, also on a app service", does that mean it does not work both locally and also on App Service? If it doesn't work locally, it may not work on App Service. So, to isolate the issue ensure it works fine locally.

Typically, the error "500.30 In-Process Startup Failure", you may occur The worker process fails. The app doesn't start.The ASP.NET Core Module attempts to start the .NET Core CLR in-process, but it fails to start. The cause of a process startup failure can usually be determined from entries in the Application Event Log and the ASP.NET Core Module stdout log.

Also, ensure that App bitness (32 vs 64 bit) is correctly configured. 
[image]

I have seen issues a common failure condition is when the app is misconfigured due to targeting a version of the ASP.NET Core shared framework that isn't present. Check which versions of the ASP.NET Core shared framework are installed on the target machine.